# Need help explaining this-> or -> in php

Tags: php, html

Can someone explain me the `$this->` and the `->` and the whole public function __construct

here is my code

```
<?php
class Person {



 public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age) {
     $this->firstname = $firstname;
     $this->lastname = $lastname;
     $this->age = $age;
 }
public function greet(){
    return "Hello, my name is" . $this->firstname . " " .$this->lastname .     "Nice to meet you ! :-)";
    }
}
$teacher = new Person ("boring", "12345", 12345);
$student = new Person("Mihail", "Dimitrovski", 1995);
 echo $student->age;
echo $teacher->greet();
?>
```

Comment: What do you don't understand? (Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/3933332)

Comment: "->" is operator that is use to access property or method of instance.

Comment: what is the value of $this?

Comment: Please start with a PHP OOP tutorial, book or other reference. We can't explain you basic OOP programming from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

A class is a blueprint. When you create a class like this for example:

```
class Person
{
    function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $age)
    {

    }

    $firstName;
    $lastName;
    $age;
}
```

you're essentially describing what a person is. Every instance of that class, every person will contain those 3 properties (first name, last name and age).

If you instantiate a new person like this:

`$student = new Person("Mihail", "Dimitrovski", 1995);`

You can use the `->` operator to access those 3 properties:

```
echo $student->firstName;
echo $student->lastName;
echo $student->age;
```

You do the same thing when you want to access those properties from within the object itself. So if you have a function within your `Person` class that prints, say, the full name:

```
function fullName()
{
    echo $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->lastName;
}
```

you need a way to reference those properties but since you don't yet have an instance you use `$this` to denote that you're refering to the current instance whatever that is

Comment: Thanks a lot you clearly explained it.

Answer (score 0):

$this-> is used to access properties or methods of a class within a class, whereas $person-> will be used when you want to access methods and variable of class outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime if you want to access a property or a method inside of an object you call it with `->`.

For example, `$student->age` calls the age property of student.

In Java it would look like this: `student.age`. It is just a way of calling methods and properties of an object.

If you call `$this->firstname` you call the properties of the class in which you are coding at the moment.

For example:

```
class Person
{
    public $name;

    public function __construct($someString, $someString2, $number)
    {
        // Write your code here.
    }

    public function greet()
    {
        echo "Hey, my name is " . $this->name.
    }
}
```

The `__construct` method will be called every time you init a new instance of an object, i.e.:

```
$studen = new Person("boring", "12345", 12345);
```

Comment: so $this means the class person?